# How to use grunt-webpack with watch and keepalive

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, watch, keep-alive, webpack

I'm trying to use [grunt-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-webpack) to continuously build my bundle. The documentation says setting `watch` and `keepalive` to `true` will make it stay and watch file changes, but when I run grunt with this task, it just builds the bundle and exits.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you please post your config and/or console output?

Answer (score 1):

For now, I found a workaround by using [grunt-exec plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-exec):

```
exec: {
    'webpack-watch': 'webpack --watch'
}
```

Works like a charm, but not as elegant as using grunt-webpack plugin.